# Play: Custom Ebean constraints

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, constraints, ebean

I just started with Play and am trying to get some custom constraints on my model.

I have found that this works

```
@Constraints.Required
@Constraints.MaxLength(15)
@Constraints.MinLength(4)
@Constraints.Pattern(value = "^\\w\\s$")
public String username;
```

But now I want to add a custom constraint with an own implementation (for checking for uniqueness) So I tried this (it was auto-completed by my IDE so it does exist)

```
@Constraints.ValidateWith(Account.UniqueValidator.class)
public String username;
```

I found somewhere (have gone through a lot of links so can't find it anymore, that the class should extend Constraints.Validator

So that is what I did.

```
 private class UniqueValidator extends Constraints.Validator<String>
{

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s) {
        return Account.find.where().eq("username", s).findRowCount() == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public F.Tuple<String, Object[]> getErrorMessageKey() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However I don't know what to return in the getErrorMessageKey value, it is a required method to implement. I looked in the play source and I found "something" what looks like this. Namely the [NotEmpty](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/834310188560715aa43b74abf86032c81fe5d4fe/framework/test/integrationtest/app/validator/NotEmpty.java) validator.

However when you look there you see it returns an Tuple, not an F.Tuple. When I change that in my code it complains that it is not an F.Tuple.

Tried to return

```
return Tuple("error.invalid", new Object[] {});
```

As done in the NotEmpty validator link above. But than it says that it needs "new" before Tuple, but that gives me an class with [a bunch](https://gist.github.com/Matthijn/6555710) of required methods to implement. So I guess that is not really the way to go.

---

When I look at the documentation of play [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.1.1/validation) I need to use the @CheckWith annotation, but when I choose that it says that it cannot find the @CheckWith annotation.

I am lost. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Note that `F.Tuple` is a template type which requires two template arguments, but in the `return` statement that you tried, you did not specify any template arguments.

In order to make your code work, simply change the line

```
return Tuple("error.invalid", new Object[] {});
```

to

```
return new Tuple<String, Object[]>("error.invalid", new Object[] {});
```

Alternatively, you could write

```
return F.Tuple("error.invalid", new Object[] {});
```

In this statement, `F.Tuple` is a static factory method which constructs and returns a `Tuple` with the correct template arguments.